# jquery has() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Let's say I have this markup:

```
<div class="comment">
  <span class="test">some content here</span>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>

<div class="comment">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

I want to check if `span.test` exists within `div.comment` and if exists to  hide  all the  `div.comment`  and to show just the `div.comment` in which `span.test` doesn't exist.

I'm stuck here :

```
 if($("span.test").length) {
    $(".element:has(span.test)").hide();
```

I don't know how to continue this to achieve what I want.

Any suggestions on how can I make this work ?

Comment: I don't see any calls to `.has()`

Comment: Won't this just do the trick? `$(".test").parent().hide();`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div.comment").filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('span.test').length
}).hide();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6SGWY/)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) like this

```
$('.comment:has(span.test)').hide()
```

Or [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$('.comment').has('span.test').hide()
```

Comment: +1, I honestly didnt knew the `has()` function. Is it a "new" function, 1-2 years? Cannot find out when it is introduced.

Comment: @davidkonrad it says the `:has()` psuedo selector was added in `jQuery 1.1.4` and the `.has()` was added in `jQuery 1.4` so you can use this as a reference as to when they came out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Release_history

Answer (score 2):

This will hide all comments with a `span.test`

```
$('.comment span.test').parent('.comment').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this-

```
$("span.test").closest('.comment').hide(); // hide comment that contains .test
```